# Manipulation of integral

Tags: calculus, integration

I came across a manipulation that I didn't completely understand in Jean Tirole's *Sequential Screening With Positive Selection* (Econometrica, 84, 4, July 2016, page 1305). It's a silly question, and not fundamental to understand the paper, but I would be grateful if anyone could guide me through the missing steps. The author manipulates the right hand side of the first equation into the second equation (using $U(\underline{\theta})=0$). $F(\centerdot)$ is the cumulative distribution of $\theta$.

\begin{equation}
... = \int_{\underline{\theta}}^{\overline{\theta}}U(\theta)dF(\theta)
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
... = \int_{\underline{\theta}}^{\overline{\theta}}\frac{dU(\theta)}{d\theta} [1-F(\theta)]d\theta
\end{equation}

Any insights will be appreciated.

Comment: The manipulation is integration by parts.

Comment: @Christopher Wong thanks!